# Creating tool in ArcGIS Pro that takes parameters from users (e.g. geodatabase filename) and shows report on screen

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, parameters

Yesterday, I got a help from this website and wrote the following code to create a new script with a hard-coded geodatabase filename, that lists the feature classes it contains to the console.

```
import arcpy
import os
arcpy.env.workspace = r"Q:\UtahCounty\Buildings.gdb"
featureclasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for fc in featureclasses:    
    print(fc)
```

Now, I am trying to create a tool in ArcGIS Pro, connected to the script, that takes parameters from users (initially, the geodatabase filename) and shows the report on the screen.

```
import arcpy
import os   

print (“choose a geodatabase.”)

geodatabase = arcpy.GetParameter(0)

arcpy.env.workspace = geodatabase

featureclasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for fc = in featureclasses
    print (fc)
```

This is what I came up with, but how could I make it so that if a user inputs something that is not a filename, it gives them a error message and ask them to try again?

I know I can use if statement, but I do not know how to write it.

Comment: Have you reviewed [Setting script tool parameters](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/setting-script-tool-parameters.htm)?  If so, what parameter data type did you use for the first parameter on your tool dialog?

Comment: If your tool is configured correctly, it would not be possible for your users to enter a file that does not exist and is not a geodatabase.  However, if you really do want to check this afterwards, you can use `if not arcpy.Exists(geodatabase):` and `arcpy.Describe(geodatabase)`.

Comment: The `print (“choose a geodatabase.”)` statement in a script tool is not of any use.  The user will not get to see it before the tool runs.  The script part of the tool only runs AFTER all of the parameters have been entered by the user in the ArcPro (GUI) part of the tool, which then sends them to the script when it runs the script.

Comment: I want the parameter to be a path to the geodatabase that a user chose. For example, I want a user to type in something like r"Q:\UtahCounty\Buildings.gdb", and it shows all the featureclasses that the geodatabase contains.

Comment: OK. I still want to display a message saying something like that print message tho. Should I use AddMessage instead?

Comment: If you want to see a message in the Results then you need `arcpy.AddMessage()` rather than `print()`.

Comment: You could use a file open dialogue to select a database in your system.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. but I think I should repost my question. I added more detail, so I would appreciate if you could help me